# separar el mensaje en usuario, fechaHora y mensaje para luego introducirlos en un Arraylist

Tags: java, string

Tengo un problema con un constructor de una clase que estoy creando. En principio el constructor recibe un Scanner conectado a un fichero, en el cual hay una serie de mensajes con idéntica configuración (usuario, fechaHora y mensaje), por ejemplo:

```
USER_ee551c6c   2023-01-07T15:40:27 drthema: Do something today that feeds your spirit and empowers you to start the week from a higher place.
```

Lo que quiero y no consigo es separar el mensaje en los elementos que he comentado (usuario, fechaHora y mensaje) para luego introducirlos en un Arraylist. Dejo el código que tengo hasta ahora:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TweetBD {
  
   private String descripcion;
   private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

   public TweetBD(String descripcion) {
      this.descripcion = descripcion;
      this.tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();      
   }

   public TweetBD(String descripcion, Scanner leerFichero) throws ParseException {
      this(descripcion);
        while (leerFichero.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] datosTweet = leerFichero.nextLine().split("\t");
            String[] datosTweetFecha = datosTweet[1].split(" ");
            String usuario = datosTweet[0];
            String fechaHora = datosTweetFecha[0] + datosTweetFecha[1];
            String tweet = datosTweetFecha[2];
            addTweet(usuario, fechaHora, tweet);
        }
    }
      public void addTweet(String usuario, String fechaHora, String tweet) throws ParseException {
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      Date fecha = dateFormat.parse(fechaHora);
      Tweet nuevoTweet = new Tweet(usuario, fecha, tweet);
      tweets.add(nuevoTweet); 
   }
```

Gracias de antemano y cualquier duda la aclararé lo más rápido posible.

Comment: "Lo que quiero y no consigo " porque? que es lo que pasa? que deberia pasar???

Comment: @gbianchi, como he comentado lo que quiero es que cada parte del mensaje se guarde en su correspondiente String, y hasta ahora no consigo dar con la solución para separarlo correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si copio y pego el texto de ejemplo que has puesto en vez de una tabulación después del usuario hay 4 espacios (he sustituido los espacios por cuadrados para que se vea mejor):

```
USER_ee551c6c▨▨▨▨2023-01-07T15:40:27▨drthema:▨Do▨something▨today▨that▨feeds▨your▨spirit▨and▨empowers▨you▨to▨start▨the▨week▨from▨a▨higher▨place.
```

por lo que la linea en la que pones `split("\t");` no esta dividiendo correctamente el String, deberias separarlo con un  limite de cuantos elementos quieres que divida, eso puedes hacerlo con `.split(" ",2);` y luego usar un trim para quitar los espacios del principio y del final.

La siguiente linea en la que lo separas por espacios te va a dar problemas porque el mensaje esta lleno de espacios y va a separar cada palabra del mensaje en  un elemento distinto del array, por lo que deberías añadirle un limite de cuantos elementos quieres que divida, eso puedes hacerlo con `.split(" ",2);`.

El `.split(" ");` tampoco esta separando la fecha y la hora, ya que no están separadas por un espacio, sino por la T, se podría hacer con `.split("T")` y volviéndolas a juntar o reemplazando la T por un carácter vacío con `.replace("T","")`.

Quedaría algo así:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TweetBD {
      private String descripcion;    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

   public TweetBD(String descripcion) {
      this.descripcion = descripcion;
      this.tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();          }

   public TweetBD(String descripcion, Scanner leerFichero) throws ParseException {
      this(descripcion);
        while (leerFichero.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] datosTweet = leerFichero.nextLine().split(" ",2); //aqui separas el usuario del resto
            String[] datosTweetFecha = datosTweet[1].trim().split(" ",2); //aqui separas la fechay hora del resto del mensaje, el trim aqui si que haria falta ya que se habran quedado espacios despues de hacer el primer split
            String usuario = datosTweet[0].trim(); //aqui eliminas los espacios extra que pueda haber al principio o al final con el trim (aunque en principio no haria falta)
            String fechaHora = datosTweetFecha[0].replace("T","");
            //tambien se podria hacer de la siguiente forma si solo quieres usar split:
            //String[] fechaHoraaux = datosTweetFecha[0].split("T");
            //String fechahora = fechahoraaux[0]+fechahora[1];
            
            String tweet = datosTweetFecha[1].trim();
            addTweet(usuario, fechaHora, tweet);
        }
    }
      public void addTweet(String usuario, String fechaHora, String tweet) throws ParseException {
      DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      Date fecha = dateFormat.parse(fechaHora);
      Tweet nuevoTweet = new Tweet(usuario, fecha, tweet);
      tweets.add(nuevoTweet);     }
```

En caso que lo de la tabulación haya sido un error al copiarlo y pegarlo tendrías que sustituir el primer `.split(" ",2);` por `.split("\t",2);`

Answer (score 1):

"Suponiendo" que tenes el mensaje de la siguiente manera

```
String mensaje="USER_ee551c6c    2023-01-07T15:40:27 drthema: Do something today that feeds your spirit and empowers you to start the week from a higher place.";
```

Una idea seria:

1 Usar split("\s") para separar por espacios en un array auxiliar

```
String[] datos =mensaje.split("\\s");
```

2 Usar el metodo `filter` para obtener en un nuevo array los elementos diferente a los espacios

```
String[] datos2 = Arrays.stream(datos).filter(s->!s.equals("")).toArray(String[]::new);
```

3 Usar el metodo `join` para concatenar los elementos del array datos 2 apartir del indice 2 en adelante obtenido como el metodo `copyRange` para obtener el mensaje en un variable ya que en el indice 0 estara el usuario y en el 1 lafechahora

```
String usuario = datos2[0];
String fechaHora =datos2[1]; 
String tweet = String.join(" ",Arrays.copyOfRange(datos2, 2, datos2.length));
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una duda, está especificando que el separador es Tab. __String[] datosTweet = leerFichero.nextLine().split("\t");__ Como estaría la implementación en Java 7???